# Изменение значения в столбце по условию

Tags: python, pandas

В столбце 'eye' есть значение Auburn Hair, в столбце 'hair' значение unknown. Я хочу поменять unknown в столбце 'hair' на значение Auburn Hair, а для столбца 'eye' изменить на unknown, т.е. поменять местами. Я использую метод .loc

```
data.loc[data['eye'] == 'Auburn Hair', 'hair'] = 'Auburn Hair' 
data.loc[data['hair'] == 'Auburn Hair', 'eye'] = 'unknown'
```

Это рабочий вариант, но может есть более лаконичный и простой способ?

Answer (score 2):

Через `.loc` можно сразу задать значения произвольному числу колонок, в вашем случае - двум колонкам, просто указав их в `.loc` в виде списка, и справа от знака присваивания тоже должен быть список с таким же числом значений, что и число колонок:

```
data.loc[data['eye'] == 'Auburn Hair', ['hair','eye']] = ['Auburn Hair','unknown']
```

Answer (score 0):

Однострочник. Основано на https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792812/15035314 + "моржовые операторы"

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'eye': [1, 2, 3, 'Auburn Hair', 4, 5, 6], 'hair': [3, 2, 1, 'unknown', 6, 5, 4]})
print(data)
data.loc[idx, lst[::-1]] = data.loc[(idx := data.eye.eq('Auburn Hair')), (lst:=['hair', 'eye'])].values
print(data)
```

```
           eye     hair
0            1        3
1            2        2
2            3        1
3  Auburn Hair  unknown
4            4        6
5            5        5
6            6        4

       eye         hair
0        1            3
1        2            2
2        3            1
3  unknown  Auburn Hair
4        4            6
5        5            5
6        6            4
```